# Grid over lidar point cloud using LiDR

Tags: r, point-clouds, lidar, lidr

I there a way to put a grid over point cloud data using the LiDR package in R.

I want to place a 30x30m grid over a lidar data that I have and then run some statistics on each 10x10 square within the grid. Does anyone know if this is possible and what function I would use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grid_metrics()` with a `RasterLayer` as layout. From the manual:

> `res` numeric. The resolution of the output Raster. Can optionally be a RasterLayer. In that case the RasterLayer is used as the layout.